# how to delete test orders in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, orders

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.I would like to delete the orders in my Magento site. I have tried to delete it in database but that is not the proper way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think deleting in the database is ok, but I have not checked.

Comment: This may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension for delete order.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seamless-delete-order.html

Or you can use below code to delete your order.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

umask(0);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);      

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $data) {
    $id = $data['increment_id'];
     try{
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id)->delete();
        echo "order #".$id." is removed".PHP_EOL;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "order #".$id." could not be remvoved: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo "complete.";
```

Comment: "you can use blow code"? Whazzat? Does it blow away the orders?

Comment: Your "blow code" looks like it would work, but I hope nobody blindly uses it and ends up deleting orders they wanted to keep. This code blows away (deletes) ALL orders.

Comment: @buttle yes this will delete all order that's why I suggest two methods, extension will delete selected order from admin. if you want to delete all order from test environment then use this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the order related tables using phpMyAdmin or mysql client, it works. The list of the tables to be truncated along with sql queries has been mentioned in blog post [Deleting test orders in Magento](http://www.techawaken.com/deleting-test-orders-magento/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create php script in Magento root folder, copy this code into script and run script.

```
/**
 * @author Dejan Radic <dejan.radic@inchoo.net>
 */
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"><h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer. <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a> Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
$executionPath = null;
/*
 * determine Magento Edition
 */
if (file_exists('LICENSE_EE.txt')) {
    $edition = 'EE';
}elseif (file_exists('LICENSE_PRO.html')) {
    $edition = 'PE';
} else {
    $edition = 'CE';
}
if(($edition=='EE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.11.0.0.', '<')===true)
    || ($edition=='PE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.11.0.0.', '<')===true)
    || ($edition=='CE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0.0.', '<')===true)
  ){
 $executionPath = 'old';
} else {
   $executionPath = 'new';
}
$xpathEntity = 'global/models/sales_entity/entities//table';
if ($executionPath == 'old') {
    $xpathResource = 'global/models/sales_mysql4/entities//table';
} else {
    $xpathResource = 'global/models/sales_resource/entities//table';
}
$salesEntitiesConf = array_merge(
    Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->init()->getXpath($xpathEntity),
    Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->init()->getXpath($xpathResource)
);
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
/*
 * If you want delete System/Order Statuses (Status and State) you
 * hould comments below lines (46-51)
 */
$skipTables = array (
    $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status'),
    $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status_state'),
    $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status_label')
);
$salesEntitiesConf = array_diff($salesEntitiesConf, $skipTables);
/*
Multiple RDBMS Support in Magento CE 1.6+ / EE 1.11+
http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide2.pdf
2.2. Adapters:
... The new Varien_DB_Adapter_Interface was added to sign a contract that all
developed adapters must execute in order to get Magento working on an actual
database. The interface describes the list of methods and constants that can be used by             resource models...
Used below in the loop:
 * If $executionPath == 'old'
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::showTableStatus()
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::truncate()
 * Else
* Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::isTableExists()
* Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::truncateTable()
*/
while ($table = current($salesEntitiesConf) ){
    $table = $resource->getTableName($table);
    if ($executionPath == 'old') {
        $isTableExists = $connection->showTableStatus($table);
    } else {
        $isTableExists = $connection->isTableExists($table);
    }
    if ($isTableExists) {
        try {
            if ($executionPath == 'old') {
                $connection->truncate($table);
            } else {
                $connection->truncateTable($table);
            }
            printf('Successfully truncated the <i style="color:green;">%s</i> table.<br />', $table);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            printf('Error <i style="color:red;">%s</i> occurred truncating the <i style="color:red;">%s</i> table.<br />', $e->getMessage(), $table);
        }
    }
    next($salesEntitiesConf);
}
exit('All done...');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);                                                                                                                 
$ids=array(); //add order ids here
foreach($ids as $id){
  try{
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id)->delete();
     }
  catch(Exception $e)
     {
        // error message
     }
}
```